# NameError: name 'RandomCharField' is not defined

Tags: django-extensions

```
from django_extensions.db.fields import RandomCharField

class Product(models.Model):
    stock = RandomCharField(length=4, include_alpha=False)
```

> NameError: name 'RandomCharField' is not defined

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you execute `import django_extensions` and `django_extensions.VERSION` and post here?

Comment: @GabrielOshiro This version is (1, 5, 5)